# Cordova: How to include .js .css files from node_modules after npm install

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, cordova

How do i get my app to read .js and .css files after npm install?

What i did was:

```
npm install bootstrap@3
```

After which, the bootstrap folder goes into my node_modules folder. /node_modules/bootstrap I followed through with compiling the css and js files using grunt:

```
grunt dist
```

and it creates a dist folder in /node_modules/bootstrap/.

What i did now was to move the dist folder from "/node_modules/bootstrap/" into my public folder "/www" so i can include it into my page located in my public folder "/www/index.html"

But somehow this feels wrong and I'm not sure if i'm going the right way.

Looking around for some resource but just can't get much information. Anyone can provide a solution or direct me to some right resource so that i can find out more. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're actually doing fine, since bootstrap is only based on those .css & .js files.